# How to make manual query in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

I have a MYSQL query which is a little complicated, I have tried several times and searched the same query case as me on the internet, I tried it but the results were not as expected. So I decided to look for a way to use Manual Query in Laravel 8 which has the same properties as Codeigniter 3 `$this->db->query`

The question: how to make all manual queries without using the Query Builder from Laravel?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-expressions take a look this

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#running-queries ... not using query builder

Comment: I have read and tried several times over the course of several hours using raw expressions, in my question this is to create a manual query without the Laravel Query Builder

Comment: `\DB::select( 'sql query')`

Comment: @lagbox i see thanks to correct me :D

Comment: ```Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 ``` I got error this. But in phpmyadmin SQL is working

Answer (score 0):

Just Apply two step

**Step: 1** : Enable Query Builder Log

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
```

**Step: 2** : Get Last Sql Query in simplest form

```
DB::getQueryLog();
```

Must try because This two line of code really helpful when I work with complex Query in Laravel

**Note:** Write Your Query Between this two line and if you write more then one query then last query will convert in simple SQL query